# date picker bridge in Rails 3 (vhochstein fork) causing permission error in Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, activescaffold

I am trying to deploy an app to Heroku for the first time. The app uses AS  (vhochstein fork). The problem is that I am getting this error:

```
/usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/fileutils.rb:1263:in `initialize': Permission denied - /disk1/home/slugs/e363a725-2eba-49e2-8411-85c0d6979a1c/mnt/public/javascripts/active_scaffold/default/date_picker_bridge.js (Errno::EACCES)
```

It appears that AS is trying to write date_picker_bridge.js. So far, I have done this:

- Run my local WEBrick server in production mode, accessed the local site, and committed the changed date_picker_bridge.js file.
- Added `config.action_controller.perform_caching = false` to environments/production.rb

Apparently, AS is still trying to write the file. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed in latest version

https://github.com/vhochstein/active_scaffold/issuesearch?state=closed&q=heroku#issue/96